# Regex to replace Q_FOREACH with C++ for loop

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-2017, find

Prior to C++11 introduction, and thanks to Qt framework, I've always made use of `Q_FOREACH(element, container)` loop in my code.

Now, I would like to replace it with C++11 for loop in the form:
`for(element : container)`

I work under Visual Studio 2017 and I would like to use its Find & Replace utility by using Regular expressions:

[image]

What is the regular expression I should write in the "Find what:" input field and what is the relative "Replace with:" string?

As a first attempt I've tried to set in the "find what":

```
Q_FOREACH(\w, \w)
```

but no match was found. What am I doing wrong?

Here follows some test cases:

```
Q_FOREACH(Class instance, this->classes())    -->  for (Class instance : this->classes())
Q_FOREACH(int v, vector)    -->  for (int v : vector)
Q_FOREACH   (int v  , vector)    -->  for (int v : vector)
```

So rules are:

- replace `Q_FOREACH` keywork with `for`
- any word from `(` to `,` has to be preserved
- replace `,` with `:`
- any word from `,` to `)` has to be preserved

Comment: You need to escape your parentheses: `Q_FOREACH\(\w, \w\)`

Comment: Done, still no match found

Comment: Alright, what is the format of `element` and `container`? Can you provide some test cases?

Comment: Try `\bQ_FOREACH\s*\(\s*([^,]+?)\s*,\s*` = > `for ($1 : `

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @StephenLeppik But it handles whitespace better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture groups should work in most major engines:

```
\bQ_FOREACH\s*\((.*?),
```

Replace that with:

```
for ($1 :
```

https://regex101.com/r/v56HBk/1

Comment: Great you fixed it now by adding `\s*` - so my pattern was not bad after all :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually, I came across that while [testing it](https://regex101.com/r/v56HBk/1).

Comment: I'd advise to not test a .NET pattern at an online tester that does not support .NET regex, although right now, there should be no issue unless there can be a line break after `Q_FOREACH`. In VS  S&R, `\s` does not match a carriage return.